# How I can find value in priority queue?

Tags: c++, queue, priority-queue

I would like to find a node in my priority queue but I did not find a solution :(
If you have a solution, I'm interested.

Thx for help.

Comment: Without any code? Nice try...

Comment: A `priority_queue` only has 2 operations defined: insert at a given priority, and retrieve the item with the highest priority. If you need anything else, `priority_queue` is not the right container.

Comment: It would help to know what you needed this for – the whole purpose of a priority queue is normally that you don’t need this operation.

Comment: @syam what if you need to know what a specific elements current priority is. `int priority = pq.find() - pg.begin();`

Comment: Can you give more information about your need?

Comment: @H2CO3 I didn't understand your comment... rhm..

Comment: @helock Typically when you ask a question on SO you provide a small compilable example of what you are trying to accomplish. This way we know what you've already tried and there is a better chance the suggested solutions will work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you really need to search through a `std::priority_queue` and want to do it efficiently you can derive a new class and add a `find` member function. Since you are not adding any additional state you do not have to worry about slicing or other issues since `std::priority_queue` is not polymorphic.

```
#include <queue>
template<
    class T,
    class Container = std::vector<T>,
    class Compare = std::less<typename Container::value_type>
> class MyQueue : public std::priority_queue<T, Container, Compare>
{
public:
    typedef typename
        std::priority_queue<
        T,
        Container,
        Compare>::container_type::const_iterator const_iterator;

    const_iterator find(const T&val) const
    {
        auto first = this->c.cbegin();
        auto last = this->c.cend();
        while (first!=last) {
            if (*first==val) return first;
            ++first;
        }
        return last;
    }
};
```

Comment: Just a question, what is this->c ?

Comment: `c` is the underlying container. It's of type `Container` passed as a template parameter and is specified in the C++ language standard so it'a guaranteed to always be there.

Comment: [CCPReference.com](http://en.cppreference.com) is a wonderful for C++ and the Standard Library. [Here is the documentation for `std::priority_queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue).

Comment: Yeah I saw at once, thx you

Answer (score 5):

If you do not care about the performance, you can declare an `iterator` to traverse the priority_queue's container. But in C++, the underlying container is been declared as `protected`, and can not be accessed directly.

One of my solution to get the iterator of the container is declaring a new class inheriting from `std::priority_queue`.

```
typedef int Val_TYPE;
typedef vector<Val_TYPE> Container_TYPE;
typedef priority_queue<Val_TYPE, Container_TYPE> pri_queue;

class Queue: public pri_queue{
public:
    Container_TYPE::iterator begin(){
        return pri_queue::c.begin();
    }
    Container_TYPE::iterator end(){
        return pri_queue::c.end();
    }
}Q;
```

Then you can get the iterator of the container.

```
Q.push(4);
Q.push(3);
Q.push(35);
for(vector<int>::iterator p=Q.begin(); p!=Q.end(); p++)
cout << *p << endl;
```

---

In order to be more efficient, for example looking for data by certain keys, you can use `pointers to data`.

Suppose the class `Data` holds each item of your data. `Data.key` is the key for search and `Data.value` is the priority in `priority_queue`.

```
struct Data{
    VALUE_TYPE value;
    KEY_TYPE key;
    ...
    ...
};
```

Store all your data in a separate collection, for example an array or an link list.

```
Data data[MAX];
```

Define a new struct which stores the pointer for certain one `data[i]`

```
struct Node{
    Data* data;
    Node(Data* ptr){data=ptr;}
};
```

Use a `priority_queue` and another data structure support search i.e. `binary search tree`, `hash`. Here I use `multimap`.

Maintain a `priority_queue` of `Node` and a `multimap` of `Node` at the same time.

```
struct cmp1{
    bool operator(Node a, Node b){ return a.data->value < b.data->value; }
};

struct cmp2{
    bool operator(Node a, Node b){ return a.data->key < b.data->key; }
};

priority_queue<Node, vector<Node>, cmp1> q;

multimap <KEY_TYPE, Node, cmp2> d;

for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
    q.push(Node(&a[i]));
    d.insert(a[i].key, Node(&a[i]));
}
```

Then you can get data's `pointer` by key using multimap `d`. The need for priority_queue is  also satisfied by using priority_queue `q`.

All of the above is just using pointers.

Comment: You don't need to include comparison functions. The template parameter defaults to `std::less` for both `map` and `priority_queue`

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Maybe you didn't understand me. I mean to use a `priority_queue` and `multimap` to store the `pointer` of data. So I need to write my own comparison functions.

Comment: Using two containers is unnecessary and even if you do your comparison functions will cause them to be ordered differently. Move the comparison function into `Node` and you have one less explicit dependency to deal with. Storing both the key and the value in `Data` is unnecessary, it's already managed by the containers. You would be better off writing your own container adapter.

Comment: there is no need to define  a new class and then iterate through it. The same can be done passing it to a function which pops and searches for  elements in the queue.